# Exporting pandas pivot table to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pivot-table

I have made a pivot table in pandas and styled it to be various shades of green using the following:

```
mapping = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
df = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=mapping)
```

I am trying to use the following code to save it to a csv file called "output.csv":

```
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

But the following error is being returned:

```
AttributeError: "Styler" object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: error is clear, the object returned from `style` is a `Styler` object, you probably don't want to assign back to `df` on that line

Answer (score -1):

As I know, csv file fromat is a pure text file (coma delimited). If you change extension to txt you open it in notepad. So there is no possibility to add colour/gradient/border in CSV file/TXT file.